# My inner div should stay inside outer div which is (background)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My buttons and text should remain on background size and be responsive.

[image]

[image]

This happens when I zoom in.

CSS-

```
#bg { 
height: 100vh;
background-image: url('../../assets/img/2.png'); /*  Background Image Link */   
background-size: 102%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;
}

.container1 {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

What I`m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS it should be: `background-size: cover;`

```
#bg {
height: 100vh;
background-image: url('../../assets/img/2.png');
background-size: cover; /*Change Here*/
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: There is no difference... But my background-size is 102% because I`m using mouseevent...

Comment: What `background-size: 102%` does is filling up the 102% of your `#bg`, however, zooming in acts the same as responsive that's why your text and buttons are stacking. But the background only covers the 102% of the browser's width, not the height.

Comment: I`m using mouse event because if background-size was cover, when I`m moving with cursor, it will leave a white right margin... I changed in my code :cover, but nothing happens. The problem is from container1.. some margins, don`t know...